# Paypal button not showing at first time

Tags: dom, ionic4, paypal-buttons

While **registering** a user I have a **payment page(first payment page)** where I am using Paypal express checkout button.

If user don't want to pay there then he/she can pay from their **profile page(second payment page)**

Problem is:

1. While registering, Paypal button showing at first payment page but not on the second payment page.
2. While login, Paypal button showing on second payment page because we won't navigate to first payment page while login.
3. So, I think while registring, it renders the Paypal  from first payment page then it won't be able to render it for the second payment page.
4. and while login, it doesn't have first payment page so it just renders  from second payment page successfully.

How can I refresh the  element while registring a user?

Answer (score -1):

Make Sure That your id is same as same which u mentioned in body tag `.render('place that id which u mentioned above');`

Paypal button will show when your mentioned id will same as same of the script `tag(render(id will be here))`